# hyperledger composer post method:how to pass parameter in post method

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I want to pass parameters to an url using post method in hyperledger composer, but i didn't found any example of it. I only found one example in sample code of composer..

```
 function handlePost(postTransaction) {
 var url = 'https://composer-node-red.mybluemix.net/compute';

  return post( url, postTransaction)
  .then(function (result) {
    // alert(JSON.stringify(result));
      postTransaction.asset.value = 'Count is ' + result.body.sum;
      return getAssetRegistry('org.example.sample.SampleAsset')
      .then(function (assetRegistry) {
          return assetRegistry.update(postTransaction.asset);
      });
  });
```

}

In third parameter of post method how should i pass the objects.for example in above i want to pass postTransaction.asset.value to the specified url..
    url string
  The URL to post the data to

typed  Typed
 The typed instance to be posted. The instance will be serialized to JSON.

options    object
 The options that are passed to Serializer.toJSON

i want to use option parameter...

Answer (score 0):

There is now an experimental feature in the Composer code to solve this problem - the post you are using can be replaced by using the `request` module from NodeJS The details are in the following 2 docs on Github:

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3092

https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/pull/3600